# Dynamic allocation with class

Tags: c++, class, dynamic

I am learning Class and I want to write a code that insert value into an array that have been allocated dynamically. I want my program to increase memory allocation of the array by *2 if the current size of the array is full, and also copy the precedent value of the array into the bigger one. (I want to do this manually and not use vector).

Here is the code I wrote. I edited my code after your comments, and know I respect the rule of three. All is working but when I create the function alias my program doesn't work anymore. I spend lot of time to try different possibility, but don't find something that work. Can you explain why, and how can I correct code.

Main

```
int main()
{
    Data one(2), second;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        one.add(i);
    second.alias(one);
    one.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Header File

```
    #pragma once
class Data
{
private:
    int* _database;
    int _size;
    int _currentSize;
public:
    Data();
    Data(int size);
    Data(const Data& init);
    ~Data();

    void display();
    void add(int value);
    void alias(Data source);
};
```

Class file

```
   #include "Data.h"
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

Data::Data()
{
    this->_database = new int[2];//Default value = 2
    this->_currentSize = 0;
    this->_size = 2;
}
Data::Data(int size)
{
    this->_database = new int[size];
    this->_size = size;
    this->_currentSize = 0;
}
Data::Data(const Data& init)
{
    if (this->_database != nullptr)
    {
        int* tmp = new int[init._size];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->_currentSize; i++)
            *(tmp + i) = *(init._database + i);

        delete[] this->_database;

        this->_database = tmp;
        this->_size = init._size;
        this->_currentSize = init._currentSize;
    }
}

Data::~Data()
{
    if (this->_database)
        delete[] this->_database;
}

void Data::display()
{
    cout << "Size: " << this->_size << endl;
    cout << "Current size: " << this->_currentSize << endl;
    cout << "Values:";
    for (int i = 0; i < this->_currentSize; i++)
        cout << *(this->_database + i) << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
void Data::add(int value)
{
    if (this->_currentSize < this->_size || this->_currentSize > this->_size)
    {
        *(this->_database + _currentSize) = value;
    }
    else
    {
        int* tmp = new int[this->_currentSize*2];

        for (int i = 0; i < this->_currentSize; i++)
            *(tmp + i) = *(this->_database + i);

        *(tmp + this->_currentSize) = value;

        delete[] this->_database;
        this->_database = tmp;
   
        this->_size = this->_currentSize*2;
    }
    this->_currentSize++;
}

void Data::alias(Data source)
{
    this->_database = source._database;
    this->_currentSize = source._currentSize;
    this->_size = source._size;
}
```

Comment: 1: Add an assignment operator (see rule of 3). 2: When your `tmp` value on the stack gets destroyed it free's its memory, which you've also given to `this` in `add`. Use `std::swap` and let the temporary cleanup instead.

Comment: What's wrong with vector?

Comment: `this->_currentSize = value;` doesn't make sense. You're putting the value in the size instead of writing it into the array.

Comment: @MikeVine I see rule of 3 in the forum. But I don't understand very well how to build it in my example, (You mean copy assignment operator, or copy operator). Can you help me achieve this. If you can help me doing this without std::swap it will be better because I want to write all manually in order to understand what I do. Thanks

Comment: *But I don't understand very well how to build it in my example,* -- Then you're not ready to write classes that are safely copyable and assignable.  -- *I want to write a simple code* -- No, it is not "simple" for a beginner or for someone not familiar with writing classes that have correct copy semantics.   If someone were to actually post a working, correct example of what you're trying to do, you will see it is much more involved.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I edit my code respected rule of 3, but still don't work

Comment: `if (this->_database != nullptr)` -- Why are you deleting memory in the copy constructor, and why are you checking anything here?  The copy constructor is supposed to create a *brand new* object -- what is there to delete, and what is there to check for?   You know there is nothing there, because again, the object is brand new.  Second, the pointer is not initialized -- not only is the `delete[]` not supposed to be there, you are accessing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: When the copt constructor starts, NONE of the members of "this" have defined values - ALL of them are uninitialized.  The first thing you do in the copy constructor is `if (this->_database != nullptr)` but accessing uninitialized variables is undefined behaviour - in your case, the garbage value in `this->_database` isn't nullptr but also doesn't point anywhere (it's uninitialized) and then you try to `delete[] this->_database;` but `this->_database` is still uninitialized.  Actually you are lucky that it crashed because undefined behaviour allows ANYTHING to happen...